# No entiendo como acaba dando el resultado. Pero el código es correcto

Tags: python

Lo que hace es sumar los valores del diccionario `y` con la cadena `s`. En las dos últimas lineas me pierdo. Me gustaría que me ayudarais a seguir la corriente del programa.

```
def calculate(y,s):
    result = 0
    keys = y.keys()
    for c in keys:
        palabra = c.split("@")
        if palabra[0] == s:
            result += y[c]
    return result
```

Comment: No sé por que no me deja formatear el código

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El `for` lo que hace es recorrer las claves de tu diccionario, las claves por lo que veo llevan un `@` en ellas, entonces el metodo `split` divide las claves y las guarda en una lista que tu llamas `palabra`.

Una vez dividida, `palabra[0]` contendra lo que tenga la clave antes del `@`, es decir, que si tu clave es `algo@otroalgo`, `palabra[0]`, contendra `algo` como dato.

después de eso compara que `palabra[0]` sea igual a la cadena `s` que mandaste a la función, y suma los valores de tu diccionario que coincidan (el valor debería ser un único valor numérico ya que definiste `result=0`).

ejemplo

```
#definimos un diccionario y una cadena de prueba
y = {"clave1@algo": 1, "clave1@algo2": 5, "clave2@algo3": 10}
s = "clave1"

#llamamos a la función
calculate(y,s)


#Aqui la definición de la funcion
def calculate(y,s):
    result = 0

    #keys guarda las claves, con el diccionario de prueba de quedaria
    #keys = ["clave1@algo1", "clave1@algo2", "clave2@algo3"]
    keys = y.keys()    

    #Recorremos las claves
    for c in keys:

        #Palabra quedaria asi en cada iteracion
        #iteracion1 -> palabra = ["clave1", "algo1"]
        #iteracion2 -> palabra = ["clave1", "algo2"]
        #iteracion3 -> palabra = ["clave2", "algo3"]
        palabra = c.split("@")

        #comparamos palabra[0] de cada iteracion con la cadena de prueba
        #iteracion1 -> compara "clave1" y "clave1". Entra
        #iteracion2 -> compara "clave1" y "clave1". Entra
        #iteracion3 -> compara "clave1" y "clave2". No Entra
        if palabra[0] == s:

            #Y ahora solo suma los valores de las coincidencias
            #Los cuales serian y["clave1@algo1"], y["clave1@algo2"]
            #Que sus valores son 1 y 5
            #Por lo cual result terminara con valor de 6
            result += y[c]
    return result
```

Espero sea lo que estabas buscando, saludos.